# How to find area using integration in a curve bounded by a straight line?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

[image]

Hope you are well.

I'm stuck on this question. I found the coordinated of A and B in the following way:

As we know that the equation of the curve is $y = (x-4)^2$ and we know that the line is $y =4$, so I did:

$(x-4)^2 = 4 $

$(x-4) (x-4) = 4$

$x^2 - 4x - 4x + 16$

$x^2 - 8x +16 = 4$

$x^2 - 8x +12 = 0$

Then I solved the equation:

$x^2 - 8x +12 = 0$

$(x-2)(x-6) =0 $

$x = 2, x = 6$

.Also, I found the coordinates of C:

$y = (x-4)^2$

$y = (0-4)^2$

$y = 16$

Then I integrated $y = (x-4)^2$ between $2$ and $6$ (A and B).

From here on, I don't know what to do.

How do I find the area?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might integrate the inverse function of $y=(x-4)^2$, from the limits $y = A_y$ to $C_y$ where $X_y$ means the $y$- coordinate of $X$. Then you may use the triangle containing the shaded area.

Comment: Note that the area is the same as the area bound between the curve $y=x^2$ and $y=4,$ which may be slightly easier to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

I would integrate with respect to $y$, and not $x$.

First, we identify the intersection points.  This is easy.  If $y = 4$ and $y = (x-4)^2$, then $4 = (x-4)^2$ or $x \in \{2, 6\}$; thus $$A = (2,4), \quad B = (6,4).$$  Since $C$ is the $y$-intercept of the parabola corresponding to $x = 0$, we simply have $$C = (0, 16).$$

Next, we find the equation of the line $\ell$ passing through $B$ and $C$.  This is accomplished via the two-point formula
$$y - y_0 = \frac{y_1 - y_0}{x_1 - x_0}(x-x_0)$$
where the line passes through $(x_0, y_0) = (0,16)$ and $(x_1, y_1) = (6,4)$.  This gives us
$$y = \frac{4 - 16}{6-0} (x - 0) + 16 = -2x + 16.$$

Next, we express the **left** branch of the parabola and the line $\ell$ as functions of $y$. The parabola is just
$$x = h(y) = 4 - \sqrt{y},$$ and the line is
$$x = g(y) = \frac{16-y}{2}.$$

Then the desired area is simply the integral over the interval $y \in [4, 16]$ of the larger function minus the smaller (with respect to the $x$-value):
$$\int_{y=4}^{16} g(y) - h(y) \, dy = \int_{y=4}^{16} \frac{16-y}{2} - (4 - \sqrt{y}) \, dy.$$  The rest is straightforward.

This strategy works because the desired area can be found by slicing the region into horizontal strips of differential width $dy$, in which the length of the strip is equal to the difference of the right endpoint which lies on the line $\ell$ and the left endpoint which lies on the left branch of the parabola $y = (x-4)^2$.  All that is needed is to express the $x$-coordinte of those endpoints as a function of the $y$-coordinate.  This avoids having to set up two separate integrals if we were to integrate with respect to $x$, since the lower boundary of the region with respect to $x$ is a piecewise function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. How did you express y= (x-4)^2 and -2x + 16  as functions of y.

Comment: @YasmeIbish You just solve for $x$ in those equations.  $y = (x-4)^2$ implies $\pm \sqrt{y} = x-4$, hence $x = 4 \pm \sqrt{y}$, where the negative root is taken to get the left branch.  For $y = -2x + 16$, solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.

Comment: Thanks, which one is the left and right branch of the parabola?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that for the shaded region, for all values of $y \in (4, 16)$, $x$ is bound between left part of the curve $y = (x-4)^2$ and segment $BC$.

For the left part of the curve, $x = 4 - \sqrt y$

Now we need to find the equation of line passing through $BC$.

For curve $y = (x-4)^2$,

- At $x = 0, y = 16$. Coordinates of point $C (0, 16)$
- At $y = 4, x = 2, 6$. Coordinates of point $B (6, 4)$

Equation of the line through $BC$, $ ~\displaystyle y - 16 = \frac{16-4}{0-6} \cdot x$

$\implies \displaystyle x = 8 - \frac y2$

Finally the bound of $y$ is $(4, 16)$

So the integral should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_4^{16} \int_{4 - \sqrt y}^{8 - y/2} ~ dx ~ dy$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you explain this a bit more? i found the equation of BC to be y= -2x+16, but what do I do with it now?

Comment: For any $y$ between $4, 16$, if you draw a horizontal line segment in the shaded region, where does it start and where does it end? Can you see the start is the left side of the parabola and the end is the line segment $BC$?

Comment: To find left side of the parabola, note $y = (x-4)^2 \implies x = 4 \pm \sqrt y$. The one with minus sign belongs to left of the vertex of the parabola.

Comment: Yep, I now understand that, but what's after this? What do with this info?

Comment: So left bound of $x$ is $4 - \sqrt y$ and right bound is $(16-y)/2$ or $8 - y/2$. So you integrate $(16-y)/2 - (4 - \sqrt y)$ between $y = $ and $y = 16$. I wrote the same thing in my answer using double integral.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Call (as seen on the figure) $D$ the point $(0,4)$, $ \ A'(2,0)$,$ \ B'(6,0)$ (projections of $A$ and $B$ onto the $x$ axis).

Compute the curvilinear area $COA'A$ under the curve between $x=0$ and $x=2$ using this integration:

$$A_1=\int_0^2(x-4)^2dx=[\frac13x^3-4x^2+16x]_0^2=\frac{56}{3}$$

add it the area of rectangle $A'B'BA$, which is $4 \times 4= 14$ giving $$A_2=\frac{56}{3}+14$$

Finally subtract $A_2$ to the area of the trapezium $COB'B$ which is equal to $$A_3=6 \frac{16+4}{2}=60.$$

giving the final result :

$$A_4=\dfrac{82}{3}$$

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: Still no comment on this answer today. Think that this site is based on dialog.